# Unnamed columns - rename - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I am trying to rename unnamed columns in my data frame.
Value of the 1st row in this column is expected to become a name of that column. If a column doesn't contain Unnamed, its name should remain unchanged.

I try to achieve it this way:

```
    for col in columns:
     if 'Unnamed' in col:
       df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0])
       break
```

In this case each column is renamed. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.where.html) with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), it replace if `False`, so inverted mask by `~`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed 1':['a', 2], 'col':['b',8]})
    
df.columns = df.columns.where(~df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed'), df.iloc[0])
print (df)
   a col
0  a   b
1  2   8
```

Your solution is possible change by loop Series with first row:

```
new = []
for col, v in df.iloc[0].items():
    if 'Unnamed' in col:
        new.append(v)
    else:
        new.append(col)
df.columns = new
```

Same in list comprehension:

```
df.columns = [v if 'Unnamed' in col else col for col, v in df.iloc[0].items()]
```

Comment: Oh I see my mistake. It is the answer to my question. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can rename unamed columns as shown below

```
df = df.rename({'Unnamed: 0':'NewName1'})
```

If multiple unnamed columns then use index based on occurance of unnamed column

```
df = df.rename({'Unnamed: 0':'NewName1','Unnamed: 1':'NewName2'})
```